# bootstrap-css checkbox disable write to haml syntax issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haml

this is my write in haml file:

wrong:

```
.checkbox.disabled
  %label
    %input{type: "checkbox", value: "", "disable"}
      Option two is disabled
```

then found:

> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_DEND

right:

```
.checkbox.disabled
  %label
    <input type="Checkbox" value="" disabled>
      Option two is disabled
```

problem is:

> how can i write right using haml syntax rather than html syntax ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is syntax - 1 for **HAML** to add `.disabled` class

```
.checkbox.disabled
 %input#checkbox-3{:name => "", :type => "checkbox"}/
 %label{:for => "checkbox-3"}
```

here is syntax - 2 for **HAML** to add `disabled` attribute

```
.checkbox
 %input#checkbox-3{:disabled => "disabled", :name => "", :type => "checkbox"}/
 %label{:for => "checkbox-3"}
```

both syntax will work. it depends upon you CSS what you want to use (Class or attribute ). so I wrote both examples